# guile2.0 conflicts guile?

Tags: make, dependencies, pacman, gdb

I'm trying to install `gdb` which requires `guile2.0` as dependency.

However `guile ver.2.0.11-3` is already installed, as a dependency of `make`.
Now when `pacman` tries to install `guile2.0`, installation fails! because some of its files are already exist in `/usr/share/guile/2.0/`, `/usr/lib/guile/2.0/` and `/usr/lib/guile/2.0/` directory. they belong to `guile` installation.

Does `gdb` conflicts with `make`? Is it safe to force replace `guile` by `guile2.0`?

**Update:** 
I'm using  4.1.15-3-ARCH.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using? pacman suggests Arch Linux, but the guile2.0 package there is version 2.0.14-1 and the guile package is version 2.2.2-1. If you're using Arch Linux, update all packages first.

Comment: Thank you. Updated the system, and problem has gone. So there is no confliction in latest versions. Could you please write your answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved uninstalling first make and guile, then I installed gdb and its dependencies (guile2.0). Finally, I re-installed make.

These are the commands:

```
# pacman -R make guile
# pacman -S gdb
# pacman -S make
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I updated system without any successful backup, and there is no confliction anymore. So unfortunately I'm not able to approve your solution.